# how to call mediaplayer setOnCompletionListener using unity native method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

i want to using unity native method call mediaplayer setOnCompletionListener as follows:

```
 mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() { 
@Override 
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) { 
            Log.i(LOGTAG, "onComplete hit"); 
            mp.stop(); 
            mp.release(); 
        } 
});
```

i know i can put the above code at the android ,and generate jar ,then put it the unity project. but i donot want to that ,i like

```
    AndroidJavaObject mediaPlayer = new AndroidJavaObject("android/media/MediaPlayer");



    IntPtr setSurfaceMethodId = AndroidJNI.GetMethodID(mediaPlayer.GetRawClass(),"setSurface","(Landroid/view/Surface;)V");
    jvalue[] parms = new jvalue[1];
    parms[0] = new jvalue();
    parms[0].l = androidSurface;


    AndroidJNI.CallVoidMethod(mediaPlayer.GetRawObject(), setSurfaceMethodId, parms); 

    mediaPlayer.Call("setDataSource", filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

i have solve my question :

public class CompletionCallback : AndroidJavaProxy {

```
    public CompletionCallback()
    :base("android.media.MediaPlayer$OnCompletionListener") {
    }

    void onCompletion(AndroidJavaObject mp) {
        CommonUtil.showToast("finish");
    }
}
```

using AndroidJavaProxy